# remove array from multidimensional array with unset

Tags: php, arrays

Is it possible to remove an array from an array? This is how the array looks...

```
[1042] => Array
    (
        [contact_name] => XXX
        [email] => 
        [id] => XXX
    )

[1043] => Array
    (
        [contact_name] => XXX
        [email] => XXX
        [id] => XXX
    )
```

code...

```
foreach($contacts as &$contact){

    if(empty($contact['email']) || $contact['email'] == '')
        unset($contact);

}
```

Comment: Call unset at the desired index: `unset($array[1043]);`

Answer (score 2):

It's possible if you use the arrays keys instead of references.

```
foreach($contacts as $key => $contact){
    if(empty($contact['email']))
        unset($contacts[$key]);
}
```

I also removed the `$contact['email] == ''` since the `empty()`-check covers empty (!) strings as well.

**Note:** In general, avoid using references together with `foreach` if you can. Using them can  easily lead to unwanted side effects.

Comment: once I try I will comment on result - Thank you for the quick response

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the key and value pair when defining the foreach loop.

Knowing the key of the value (in this case a subarray) you want to unset, you can do it like below:

```
foreach($contacts as $key => $contact {
     if(empty($contact['email']) || $contact['email'] == '') {
        unset($contacts[$key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to filter out items that do not have a value in the `email` field, if that is the case then use PHP's [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) method:

```
$filtered = array_filter($array, function($contact) {
    if(!empty($contact['email']) && $contact['email'] != '') {
        return $contact;
    }
});
```

Fiddle: [Live Demo](https://3v4l.org/tKtE0)

Answer (score 0):

had to do traditional for loop and use index to remove. Could not be done with foreach loop.

**Edit**

```
 // this is the code that worded
for($i = 0; $i <= count($other_array); $i++){
    if( !array_key_exists( "testing", $other_array[$i] ) )
        unset($other_array[$i]);
}
```

Comment: You could consider adding the code to your answer to illustrate your solution.